# Returning value from code behind to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

So, i want to set my cssclass with a codebehind function that looks like this, but it doesnt work, I only get an ampty string in my final code, what am I doing wrong?

Aspx:

```
<td align="left" class="<% GetCssForUser("start") %>">
```

CodeBehind:

```
        protected string GetCssForUser(string field)
    {
        string css = "";

        switch(field)
        {
            case "start":
                css = "start";
                break;
            case "end":
                css = "end";
                break;
            case "course":
                css = "course";
                break;
            case "group":
                css = "group";
                break;
            case "teacher":
                css = "teacher";
                break;
            case "room":
                css = "room";
                break;
            case "plan":
                css = "plan";
                break;
        }

        if (User.ActiveRole == Teacher)
        {
            css += "Teacher";
        }
        else 
        {
            css += "Student";
        }

        return css;
    }
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint at the switch statement to see if it hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you messing syntax in this code

```
<td align="left" class="<% GetCssForUser("start") %>">
```

it's use like this

```
<td align="left" class="<%=GetCssForUser("start") %>">
```

i think this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
class='<%=GetCssForUser("start") %>'
```

Note the `%=` and the opening `'<` and closing `>'` (because of the later `"start"`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`<td align="left" class="<%= GetCssForUser("start") %>">`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
youControl.Attributes.Add("class", css );
```